# Is there a way of overriding the application’s info.plist?

Tags: macos, plist

The background is that I am trying to run an application in low resolution (VirtualBoxVM). In the past, it was a matter of go to the application, selecting Get Info, and selecting the Open in Low Resolution option. That appears to have disappeared in macOS Monterey.

A solution which works is to to the the application’s own `info.plist` file and making changes to the `NSHighResolutionCapable` property. That works, but it’s probably bad form to do it this way, and obviously won’t survive an update to the application.

Does macOS support some sort of per-user plist which would override `info.plist` properties?

Comment: The answer to your specific question is: _"No, there is no way to override `Info.plist` except by editing it."_ But I think your _actual_ question is: _"How do I run an app in low resolution mode in Monterey?"_ For that, there may well exist a solution.